# Playing an MOV/MP4 locally in FireFox

Tags: firefox, video, local, mpeg

This isn't clever nor fun but I'm stuck. A client of mine requires the need for a download of a presentation web site where videos can be embedded. Since OGG is a pretty obscure format for clients I ask them to upload MPEG4 encoded videos as either .mov, .mp4 or .m4v. These can be played using the HTML `<video>` or for browsers that don't support MPEG4 I use a Flash player (since that can play them).

This is fine for online and it works well.

When we go to download the presentation, the `<video>` element works fine in browsers that support MPEG4 video, even if they're local.

So we then come on to FireFox; this doesn't support MPEG4. Nor can I get Flash to locally play a video (because of security issues, unless we get them to go through the security settings but that isn't very nice).

So we resorted to using the good ol' `<embed>` tag but this is very buggy with FireFox. It works fine on a server, it even allows me to have custom controls, but locally the videos don't play.

I've had some Googling around and it seems like a security issue but want to get a definite answer. Does anyone know why it's not playing locally? The URL is fine and the file exists. I notice that it's common amongst version 4+ so could it be a codec issue? Is there another way I can get FireFox to play MPEG4s locally?

Comment: Any chance of having a small, portable local web server for the presentation so you can use `http://` URLs?

Comment: Ha, I wish! It's meant to be downloaded as a zip so that the 'client' can view it without internet, so it has to run locally.